# C++ split string with escape

Tags: c++, split

I am new in C++. I am trying to split a string which is like

```
<a:cb>:"dfddff:gh":[mjddl:]
```

My delimiter is `:`,  and entries inside `<>`, `""` or `[]` should not be split. The output should be

```
a:cb
dfddff:gh
mjddl:
```

I want to create a function which takes the following parameters

```
SplitString(string StringToSplit,char delimiter,vector<char>escapeStartList,vector<char>escapeEndList)
```

Just wanted to know if there is something already existing like this in standard library or boost.

Most of the answer on stackoverflow provides  escape sequence of quotation, here i want to use escape start and end.

Comment: See the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Comment: There is no standard way to do this. Either you split the string manually by yourself (referencing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c?rq=1)
or you could use regular expressions which you can use when you include the `#include<regex>` header-file

Comment: Check Boost tokenizer, it should do most of work: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/tokenizer/